# Auto focus for first element for form in jquery popup

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am building a form on a jquery popup. Here is the code

http://myclientwebsites.com/UnderProgress/jquery/demo/

When you click "Inline" a popup appears with a sample form on same. Now I wanted cursor to be auto focused on first input field. I tried using html5 autofoucs but it was not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) function. As an example, I focused an input with name attribute "name":

```
$('input[name="name"]').focus();
```

The HTML5 `autofocus` will only work in modern browsers, which may be why you're not seeing it

Comment: true thats correct but can u please help me in writing code. This is because this will not wont work onload. So onclicking the inline the popup comes and autofoucs should happen. I am not sure how to bind those, any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

...

`$(input[name="name"]').focus()` only works if the first element found in your form is an 'input' type... how if, the first element in your form is not an 'input' element like, 'select', 'textarea'?

This is what i did....

```
var selectors = $('input:text, select, input:radio, input:checkbox, textarea');

selectors.first().focus();
```